# Plotting multiple variables in JMeter Custom Graph

Tags: graph, jmeter

Using the below configuration I am able to plot a variable in JMeter custom graph section.
But is there a way to plot similar multiple variables in same graph?

```
<sample_variables>var1</sample_variables>
<jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_graph1.classname>org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CustomGraphConsumer</jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_graph1.classname>
<jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_graph1.title>Test Custom Graph 1</jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_graph1.title>
<jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_graph1.property.set_Y_Axis>Response Times</jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_graph1.property.set_Y_Axis>
<jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_graph1.property.set_X_Axis>Over Time</jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_graph1.property.set_X_Axis>
<jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_graph1.property.set_granularity>60000</jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_graph1.property.set_granularity>
<jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_graph1.property.set_Sample_Variable_Name>var1</jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_graph1.property.set_Sample_Variable_Name>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As of [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) it's not possible, however you can have multiple charts, one per [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)

Also JMeter [.jtl result files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) are basically CSV files so you can add another page and use i.e. [Google Charts library](https://developers.google.com/chart) for plotting whatever you want there.